# Feeding Word Embeddings into Recurrent Neural Networks

Tags: neural-networks, recurrent-neural-network, word-embeddings

I'm trying to understand how Recurrent Neural Networks use word embedding vectors as their inputs, and I've created the illustration below to reflect my current-state understanding.

I understand that word embedding is its own learning process to reduce the dimensionality of the relationship between words in a corpus, and that the number of dimensions returned is user-defined (similar to PCA). But **am I correct in understanding that once the resulting vectors are created, that each word's "embedding vector" in each statement observation is then fed into its own  x<sub>t</sub> input of an RNN**, when performing something like sentiment analysis? The application of the highlighted yellow boxes below is what I'm trying to confirm actuall happens.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your representation is correct. Sentences with word-embeddings are like multivariate time series. In your representation, you use fixed length sentences with multiple stop words as suffixes but they can be varying length as well.